# Java - Get filename from "http://www.example.com/something.php?id=1111"

Tags: java, http

After googling, I found that file name is in `Content-Disposition` header field but this link does not has this header field. Here is the link 
`http://www.songspk.link/link/song.php?songid=5558`
In web browser, above link redirects to
`http://sound6.mp3slash.net/indian/mumbai_salsa/mumbaisalsa04%28www.songs.pk%29.mp3`

The code I used :

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.songspk.link/link/song.php?songid=5558");
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
try {
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0");
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();
    Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
    for (String s : keys) {
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println("--->" + map.get(s));
    }
 } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
    conn.disconnect();
}
```

I checked all header fields and here is list

```
null
--->[HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
ETag
--->["98f85f68c5ddcf1:0"]
Date
--->[Wed, 23 Mar 2016 10:01:15 GMT]
Content-Length
--->[5777792]
Last-Modified
--->[Wed, 01 Oct 2014 22:16:54 GMT]
Accept-Ranges
--->[bytes]
Content-Type
--->[audio/mpeg]
X-Powered-By-Plesk
--->[PleskWin]
X-Powered-By
--->[ASP.NET]
Server
--->[Microsoft-IIS/7.5]
```

I need the original filename. I have no problem in using external library if it can solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [getURL()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getURL--) method of the connection, it will return already redirected url:

```
System.out.println(conn.getURL());
```

Output:

```
http://sound6.mp3slash.net/indian/mumbai_salsa/mumbaisalsa04(www.songs.pk).mp3
```